# Prove if $|z| \ge 8 $ then $|z^3+7| \ge 505$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Show that if $|z| \ge 8 $ then $|z^3+7| \ge 505$

Should I make $z = x + yi$

$|z|^2$ = $x^2 +  y^2 \ge 8^2 = 64$

How would I go on from here

Comment: Use the inverse triangle inequality - $|a-b|\ge \left||a|-|b|\right|$.

Comment: using $|z^3| = |z|^3$

Comment: @WillJagy how do I isolate the 7? Like |7| whats the modulus of 7 anyways

Comment: The modulus of a real number is just the same thing as absolute value.  You can see this by writing the real number $x$ as $x+ 0i$ and using the general modulus formula.

Comment: @tilper yea I realized that sorry about that. If I want to use the triangle inquality.I can have to get $|z|^3 >= 512$ then $|z|^3+|7| >= 512+|7|$  but in order to get $|z^3 + 7| >= 505$ I need to subtract 7 from 512.

Comment: @MingWu, as suggested by my comment and by the following 2 answers, you need to use the inverse triangle inequality, not the regular one. BTW, when using latex \ge is better than >=

Comment: @MingWu see my answer.  I think you're having issues with the signs and my answer addresses how to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

$|z^3+7|\ge ||z^3|-|7||=||z|^3-7|\ge 512-7=505$

Comment: This is what I hinted about, but the OP comment that he can't solve using it.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse triangle inequality.  In general it says $|z - w| \ge ||z| - |w||$.  In this specific case, we have
$$|z^3 + 7| = |z^3 - (-7)| \ge ||z^3| - |-7|| = ||z|^3 - 7|.$$

Now, since $|z| \ge 8$, then $|z|^3 \ge 8^3 = 512$.  Therefore $|z|^3 - 7 \ge 512 - 7 = 505$.  Since $505 > 0$, taking absolute values doesn't change the inequality.  So we see that $||z|^3 - 7| \ge 505$, which gives the desired result.

Comment: Why so much pain the minima of $|a+b|\geq |a|-|b|$

Comment: To each his own I guess but I didn't really find the process I outlined painful.  And if this is for a complex analysis course it's probably better to be rigorous and use the reverse triangle inequality.. unless they've previously established the fact you mentioned.